# How can I jail the user inside a directory

Tags: c, file, io

Lets say my I've the path `/home/sn/stuff/`. And the user now enters `../secretStuff/secret.txt`. Now the user is in `/home/sn/secretStuff` and can read everything inside of it.

How do I stop this from happening? Is it okay to just do not tolerate any .. in the path the user enters?

Comment: Check the user's input?

Comment: What do you mean by "simulate"? Depending on the OS there are different things you can do to restrict user access. In Linux for example there are file permissions and namespaces.

Comment: Do not allow an entry which point to parent?

Comment: That may be harder than you first imagine. Consider what happens if the user symlinks out of the allowed directiory.

Comment: @kaylum I'm using openSUSE and yes file permissions would work.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the user has no direct access to the file system

Comment: @kaylum with simulate I mean that I want to try out the full path before I use the path inside my program so that I can verify that the path is inside my folder

Comment: Well that's much simpler. You are the gate between the user and the files. So simply check what the user enters and not allow anything that would result in accessing a disallowed path. Isn't it as simple as that? If not then you need to make your question clearer.

Comment: I've reworded my question @kaylum. So I could just say that the user must not enter any .. in my input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to "break from jail":

- Entering an absolute path not within the jail
- Entering a relative path leading out of the jail
- Somehow constructing a link (softlink, hardlink, mount, ...) *inside* the jail to something *outside* the jail (by exploiting some other vulnerability)
- Whatever I didn't think of (see comment)

As you didn't really specify the scenario, it's hard to say what kind of potential exploits you are looking at, and how far you would want to go to avoid them.

You should, at the very least, sanity-check the user's inputs (e.g. using [`realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html), which is much more reliable than string-parsing the user input yourself and covers absolute, relative, and paths with softlinks in them in one go).

You might want to disallow access to hardlinks (using [`fstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) and checking `nlink_t`).

---

Depending on the level of security required, you might want to check [`chroot`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chroot) as well, which would allow you to cherry-pick what the user can even *see* of your system. But that requires quite some additional "plumbing".

Comment: @SvenNiehus: Caveat: System security is not my forte. If you're looking at "potential disaster" kind of requirements, you should ask this at [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com) to get all the possible scenarios covered. But your question struck me as more of the hobbyist level, for which `realpath` / `fstat` is probably sufficient.

Comment: It's for a college project so `realpath` / `fstat` should work out well. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you'd like the user to be jailed into a folder. You may want to use strncmp to check if the base folder matches your jail as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf, fprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE */
#include <string.h> /* strncmp */

#define JAIL_FOLDER "/home/user"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  if (strncmp(argv[1], JAIL_FOLDER, strlen(JAIL_FOLDER)) != 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error, folder outside of jail\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  printf("Access Granted to Folder\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This method however requires a bit of parsing in case user is already in a folder and uses a relative path.